# How can I get this MySQL query to work on MySQL 4.1.15?

Tags: mysql, database

The following query works on MySql 5 but my client has MySql 4.1.15 and this query chokes with the following error:

> #1140 - Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no
>   GROUP columns is illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause

Upgrading the clients MySql version is not an option BTW. Can someone help me rewrite this to work on the older version of MySql?

```
SELECT 
   Sum( room_rev + room_rev_future ) as weekly_room_rev, 
   Sum( (`food_rev`) + (`beverage_rev`)) as weekly_catering_rev,
   (SELECT min_sales_persons 
   FROM bdp_hotel_min WHERE 
   bdp_hotel_min.hotel_num = bdp_scorecard.hotel_num 
   AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(bdp_hotel_min.`min_override_week`) 
   < UNIX_TIMESTAMP("2011-12-02 23:59:59") 
   ORDER BY bdp_hotel_min.`min_override_week` DESC LIMIT 1 ) as override_persons,
   min_sales_persons 
FROM bdp_scorecard JOIN locations ON bdp_scorecard.hotel_num = locations.hotel_num 
WHERE bdp_scorecard.hotel_num =837 AND bdp_scorecard.hotel_num = 837 
AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(bdp_scorecard.`created_date`) >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP("2011-11-26") 
AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(bdp_scorecard.`created_date`) < UNIX_TIMESTAMP("2011-12-02 23:59:59")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't test but a group by seems like it would be needed given the error..

```
SELECT 
   Sum( room_rev + room_rev_future ) as weekly_room_rev, 
   Sum( (`food_rev`) + (`beverage_rev`)) as weekly_catering_rev,
   (SELECT min_sales_persons 
   FROM bdp_hotel_min WHERE 
   bdp_hotel_min.hotel_num = bdp_scorecard.hotel_num 
   AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(bdp_hotel_min.`min_override_week`) 
   < UNIX_TIMESTAMP("2011-12-02 23:59:59") 
   ORDER BY bdp_hotel_min.`min_override_week` DESC LIMIT 1 ) as override_persons,
   min_sales_persons 
FROM bdp_scorecard JOIN locations ON bdp_scorecard.hotel_num = locations.hotel_num 
WHERE bdp_scorecard.hotel_num =837 AND bdp_scorecard.hotel_num = 837 
AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(bdp_scorecard.`created_date`) >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP("2011-11-26") 
AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(bdp_scorecard.`created_date`) < UNIX_TIMESTAMP("2011-12-02 23:59:59")
GROUP BY override_persons, min_sales_persons
```